# RESTful API with Scala using Jersey?

Tags: java, web-services, scala

Thanks Maven archetypes the barrier to start developing of services for new RESTful APIs is very straightforward - you can get more or less a project template and start filling in your code.

Now as I am new to Scala, is there some compatibility to use/integrate with Jersey in a similarly convenient way or is there a "Scala" way? (or, would I continue with Java letting all the wiring in the standard Jersey project but delegate complex implementations to a separate Scala JAR artefact).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For building scala REST services you should look into the [play](https://www.playframework.com/) and [lagom](https://www.lagomframework.com/) frameworks.

Comment: see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773)